# Como alinear iconos en la celdas

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, font-awesome

Hola estoy utilizando la librería **fontawesome** para mostrar unas unos iconos en unas celdas

```
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
```

Intento ponerlo en la parte superior de la celda, y con`valign=”top”`  ni con  `vertical-align: top`  consigo ponerlo.

Cuando estamos visualizando la tabla en una pantalla en posición horizontal, se ve bien porque cada línea de la tabla se muestra en una sola línea.

[image]

En cambio, cuando la pantalla se deja en vertical, las líneas se muestran dobles y la celda que contiene el icono se queda en el centro, o igual algo más bajo.

[image]

Así muestro el icono

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes, width=device-width" />
 <title>Titulo</title>

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
 
  
      <style type="text/css">
        .oculto1,.oculto2,.oculto3{
            margin-left: 1%;
            display: none;
        }
        .info2_submenu1 span{
            padding-left: 15px;
        }
         td {
          vertical-align: "top";
        }

    </style>


</head>
<body>

<div>
    <p>
    <p>
    <div>
        <a><button type="button" style='width:257px; text-align: left; font: 11pt arial;' onclick="window.open('pagina.htm','_self');">
           <span><i style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue" class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Boton 1</span></button></a>
    </div>
          
    <div class="info1">
        <a href="#info1"><button type="button" style='width:257px; text-align: left; font: 11pt arial'>Libro 1</button></a>
    </div>
        <div id="<info1></info1>" class="oculto1">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><span style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">&nbsp;INDICE por artículos</a></td>
         </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><span style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">&nbsp;Cap. 1 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.</a></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
            <td><span style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td><a href="pagina.htm">&nbsp;Cap. 2 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
         

    <div class="info2">
        <a href="#info2"><button type="button" style='width:257px; text-align: left; font: 11pt arial'>Libro 2</button></a>
    </div>
        <div id="info2" class="oculto2">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><span style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">&nbsp;INDICE</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><span style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">&nbsp;Sec. 1 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><span style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">&nbsp;Sec. 2 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon. </a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><span style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="#" class="info2_ET1">&nbsp;Tema 1 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit.</a></td>
            </tr>
   <tr hidden class="info2_submenu1">
   <td></td>
       <td>
       <span style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm"><i style="color: blue" class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Cap. 1/Sec. 1 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit.</a></span><br>
       <span style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm"><i style="color: blue" class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Cap. 1/Sec. 2 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.</a></span>
       </td>
   </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
          

    <div class="info3">
        <a href="#info3"><button type="button" style='width:257px; text-align: left; font: 11pt arial'>Libro 3</button></a>
    </div>
        <div id="info3" class="oculto3">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><span style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">&nbsp;INDICE</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><span style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">&nbsp;Sec. 1 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><span style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">&nbsp;Sec. 2 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon. </a></td>
            </tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

    <div>
        <a><button type="button" style='width:257px; text-align: left; font: 11pt arial;' onclick="window.open('pagina.htm','_self');">
           <span><i style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue" class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; INDICE</span></button></a>
    </div>
    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('.info1').on('click',function(){
                $('.oculto1').slideToggle('fast');
                $('.oculto2').slideUp('fast');
                $('.oculto3').slideUp('fast');
                $('.info2_submenu1').slideUp('fast');

            });
            $('.info2').on('click',function(){
                $('.oculto2').slideToggle('fast');
                $('.oculto1').slideUp('fast');
                $('.oculto3').slideUp('fast');
                $('.info2_submenu1').slideUp('fast');

            });
            $('.info3').on('click',function(){
                $('.oculto3').slideToggle('fast');
                $('.oculto2').slideUp('fast');
                $('.oculto1').slideUp('fast');
                $('.info2_submenu1').slideUp('fast');
            });
            $('.info2_ET1').on('click',function(){
                $('.info2_submenu1').slideToggle('fast');
            });
        }); 
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Incluso he probado a alinear todo el contenido de la `<tabla>` y no lo he conseguido.

Como se puede poner el icono en la parte alta de la celda para que cuando se muestre el contenido en más de una línea, se vea bien.

[image]

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo en el que podamos reproducir el error?

Comment: Francisco llevo dos horas intentando escribir este post desde el móvil, no se si voy a poder poner el código ahorra, si no cuando llegue a casa, de todas formas no me muestra ningún error, pensaba que con poner el código de una de las tablas sería suficiente ya que el resto del código es igual

Comment: Yo directamente eliminaría el `td` donde pones el icono y lo pondría dentro del `td` justo antes del enlace. Al fin y al cabo, el icono es como si fuera un texto y lo puedes tratar como tal. ¿Has probado eso?

Comment: La idea es dejar separación, porque cuando se pone en vertical, las líneas salen doble y la segunda línea comenzaría justo debajo del primer carácter de la primera línea, necesito esa separación para diferenciar las partes del índice

Comment: He eliminado mi respuesta. No había entendido así la pregunta, te sugiero que mires la respuesta de @Shaz.

Comment: @SoCu, no entiendo como es que usando `<td valign="top"` o `<td style="vertical_align: top"`, no ha solucionado tu problema. ¿Que navegador estas usando? ¿Es acaso en email?

Comment: Hola Marcos, el navegador que estoy utilizando es Firefox, pero no se porque pero no me hacia nada, lo que preguntas de email, no se que quieres decir, si te refieres al Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería funcionar con un simple vertical-align: top;

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
        <td>Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon. Chocolate bar macaroon candy sugar plum chocolate bar caramels sweet dessert. Danish tiramisu bonbon dessert sugar plum tart fruitcake gummies. Jelly beans chupa chups gingerbread croissant. Candy canes tiramisu candy dragée icing biscuit cotton candy. Cupcake cookie bonbon cookie. Chocolate caramels oat cake sweet roll gummies powder brownie ice cream brownie. Jujubes toffee candy canes sweet roll danish jelly gummies lemon drops. Pie candy canes brownie. Gingerbread macaroon cookie gummies cheesecake. Candy canes wafer sesame snaps. Candy sweet marshmallow topping brownie topping dragée gummi bears chocolate bar. Icing chupa chups chupa chups apple pie wafer cookie jelly gummi bears sweet.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Si quisieras incluso utilizar una sola celda para ambos, lo puedes solucionar fácilmente con flexbox:

```css
td {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon. Chocolate bar macaroon candy sugar plum chocolate bar caramels sweet dessert. Danish tiramisu bonbon dessert sugar plum tart fruitcake gummies. Jelly beans chupa chups gingerbread croissant. Candy canes tiramisu candy dragée icing biscuit cotton candy. Cupcake cookie bonbon cookie. Chocolate caramels oat cake sweet roll gummies powder brownie ice cream brownie.</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Lorem ipsum...</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

El resto serían los detalles de los espacios que necesites entre el ícono y el texto.

EDICIÓN:

No debes incluir comillas cuando defines los valores preestablecidos para las propiedades de CSS, lo correcto en este caso es: `vertical-align: top;`

Tampoco debes incluir espacios consecutivos en HTML como `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`, eso es una muy mala práctica, para eso existe CSS.

Por último, cuando apliques el mismo estilo a varios elementos, (el color azul por ejemplo), lo correcto es agregarle una clase a cada uno de estos elementos y definir el estilo solo una vez en el CSS (ver .blue-text).

Idealmente el código CSS no debe estar "inline", sino que debe estar aislado del HTML, en su totalidad.

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('.info1').on('click',function(){
                $('.oculto1').slideToggle('fast');
                $('.oculto2').slideUp('fast');
                $('.oculto3').slideUp('fast');
                $('.info2_submenu1').slideUp('fast');

            });
            $('.info2').on('click',function(){
                $('.oculto2').slideToggle('fast');
                $('.oculto1').slideUp('fast');
                $('.oculto3').slideUp('fast');
                $('.info2_submenu1').slideUp('fast');

            });
            $('.info3').on('click',function(){
                $('.oculto3').slideToggle('fast');
                $('.oculto2').slideUp('fast');
                $('.oculto1').slideUp('fast');
                $('.info2_submenu1').slideUp('fast');
            });
            $('.info2_ET1').on('click',function(){
                $('.info2_submenu1').slideToggle('fast');
            });
        });
```

```css
        .oculto1,.oculto2,.oculto3{
            margin-left: 1%;
            display: none;
        }
        .info2_submenu1 span{
            padding-left: 15px;
        }
        .blue-text {
          font: 10pt comic sans ms; 
          color: blue;
        }
        td {
          vertical-align: top;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>
    <p>
    <div>
        <a><button type="button" style='width:257px; text-align: left; font: 11pt arial;' onclick="window.open('pagina.htm','_self');">
           <span><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right blue-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> Boton 1</span></button></a>
    </div>
          
    <div class="info1">
        <a href="#info1"><button type="button" style='width:257px; text-align: left; font: 11pt arial'>Libro 1</button></a>
    </div>
        <div id="<info1></info1>" class="oculto1">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><span class="blue-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">INDICE por artículos</a></td>
         </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><span class="blue-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">Cap. 1 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.</a></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
            <td><span class="blue-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td><a href="pagina.htm">Cap. 2 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
         

    <div class="info2">
        <a href="#info2"><button type="button" style='width:257px; text-align: left; font: 11pt arial'>Libro 2</button></a>
    </div>
        <div id="info2" class="oculto2">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><span class="blue-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">INDICE</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><span class="blue-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">Sec. 1 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><span class="blue-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">Sec. 2 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon. </a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><span class="blue-text"><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="#" class="info2_ET1">Tema 1 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit.</a></td>
            </tr>
   <tr hidden class="info2_submenu1">
   <td></td>
       <td>
       <span style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm"><i style="color: blue" class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Cap. 1/Sec. 1 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit.</a></span><br>
       <span style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm"><i style="color: blue" class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Cap. 1/Sec. 2 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.</a></span>
       </td>
   </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
          

    <div class="info3">
        <a href="#info3"><button type="button" style='width:257px; text-align: left; font: 11pt arial'>Libro 3</button></a>
    </div>
        <div id="info3" class="oculto3">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td><span class="blue-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">INDICE</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><span class="blue-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">Sec. 1 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon.</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><span class="blue-text"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td>
            <td style='font: 11pt arial'><a href="pagina.htm">Sec. 2 - Jujubes marzipan chocolate cake wafer biscuit. Biscuit powder danish croissant cupcake macaroon. </a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

    <div>
        <a><button type="button" style='width:257px; text-align: left; font: 11pt arial;' onclick="window.open('pagina.htm','_self');">
           <span><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right blue-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> INDICE</span></button></a>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: ¡Ups! Tienes toda la razón, leí mal.  Gracias.

Comment: Gracias Shaz, eso es lo que intentaba hacer, y lo que me ha llevado a preguntar, ya que al utilizar el `Valign="top" y `style="vertical_align: "top"` no conseguía nada, aunque tengo que decir que he copiado el archivo html para seguir en casa, y no me funciona nada, tengo celdas ocultas que al pulsar sobre ellas se muestra el contenido, en el curro funcionaba sin problemas, lo he copiado para seguir en casa y ahora ni me muestra el contenido oculto, así que mañana seguiré con el otro a ver qué ha pasado, en cualquier caso esto que has puesto es lo que busco. Gracias

Comment: Ya he visto lo que pasaba, asi que he probado con el primer codigo que es el que estoy utilizando, y al poner `vertical-align: top` yo diria que lo muestra abajo, http://funkyimg.com/i/2DmJL.png, ahora lo entiendo menos

Comment: Debe haber algún factor externo que está impidiendo que funcione, con la información que proporcionas ya te comprobé que funciona.

Comment: He puesto el código completo en el primer post, espero no haber quitado más de la cuenta, aunque es solo una parte, porque el otro es muchísimo más extenso, pero para ver el funcionamiento creo que puede valer, he intentado poner el código cada uno en una parte de los paneles, pero al final lo he vuelto a juntar todo el código porque no se ejecutaba bien, y como bien dices el código que tú has puesto funciona.

Comment: Revisa la edición de mi respuesta, tienes muchas cosas por mejorar cuando utilizas HTML y CSS.

Comment: Gracias Shaz, ahora ya he podido verlo como tiene que ser, y tienes razon hay mucho que mejorar, lo dicho... muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

estimado, para agregar un icono al lado del texto se hace mas o menos así y es con bootstraps.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3  ">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9  ">
                <span>Mi perfil</span>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </td>
</tr></table>
```

espero que te ayude.

Answer (score 1):

```css
td 
{
    height: 50px; 
    width:50px;
}

#cssTable td 
{
    text-align:center; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font: 10pt comic sans ms; color: blue"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border="1" id="cssTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: No esperaba tener respuesta tan pronto y me habéis  pillado con el teléfono jeje, con `valign="middle" ` no es para mostrarlo como en el centro de la celda,

Comment: Gracias Juan, creo que al poner `middle` es la configuracion que tiene por defecto, es como me sale a mi, y lo que intento es cambiarla para que se muestre arriba.